# Please add revisions for hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Sometimes I spend considerable amount of time placing a hat I just received, and wear it.

Then I get a new hat, and yet again, spend time to place it correctly. Wearing it causes the previous hat I wore to be gone forever, without any way to go back to it other than repeat my steps again.

It would be really awesome to have "hats revisions", where we'll see the recently used hats, and be able to go back to wear them exactly as it was before.

Idea is inspired by the Undo/Redo options in the Knitting game, and the ability to restore the last knitting even after page reload.

Answer (score 4):

If keeping a revision list would be too hard, the knitting game suggests an option that might be easier and IMO would suffice: **download/upload**.  Just as you can save your knitted hat for later use, we could have these controls in the hat rack.  It would be up to you to save configurations that you particularly care about, and the hat code wouldn't have to try to track every trivial change you make.  That seems especially important with a hat for changing hats in play.

Comment: With cookies, I don't think keeping two values per hat should be too hard.

Comment: @Cœur if you use cookies then you're inviting bug reports/support requests from people who use multiple devices and didn't realize that, among all the things they can save on SE, hats were excluded.